# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\Bipin\\Downloads\\test.jpeg'

Tags: python, image, numpy, matplotlib, imread

I am trying to run this code in jupyter notebook.

```
from scipy import ndimage as ndi
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

img=np.flipud(plt.imread('C:\\Users\\Bipin\\Downloads\\test.jpeg'))
plt.imshow(img,cmap=plt.cm.gray, interpolation='nearest')
plt.show()
```

and I get an error saying

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 
'C:\\Users\\Bipin\\Downloads\\test.jpeg'
```

But I have tried to run the code to search for a different file called DNA.jpeg, and have also tried to convert test.jpeg to test.png and run. Both of these cases work. All the files are in the same folder. I am just not able to open test.jpeg  . am i missing something here?

Does file size have anything to do with this code?

Comment: are you sure then its not `test.JPEG` note the extention in caps letter or `test.jpg`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your file path is EXACTLY the same. Case sensitive and all. The safest way is to copy the file path. To copy the full path of a file on Windows, navigate to your file in Windows Explorer then hold the shift key as you right click your file. Then select the “Copy as path” option. Paste the path into your code. You may have to do some minor modifications like adding extra backslashes to escape the first ones like you have already done.